# Android ActivityNotFoundException when starting my Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to send data through intent from one activity to another. But facing **force close** error on `button click`.

**First Activity :**

```
btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit); 
btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClass(ViewchangerActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("Name", et.getText().toString());

       startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

---

**Second Activity :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedinstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String str =b.getString("Name");

         tv.setText(str);
    }
```

---

**LogCat:**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
{org.android/org.android.DisplayActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: You got any exception? Post the logcat

Comment: Add Your Androidmanifest.xml or your logcat.

Comment: It clearly says to add your activity in manifest file

Comment: I have added my LogCat if that makes any help . thank you in advance.

Comment: <activity android:name=".DisplayActivity"></activity>   ADD IT IN MANIFEST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make Sure You have Registered Your **DisplayActivity** in Manifast.xml as:

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayActivity"></activity>
```

and plz Clean your Project from **Project->Clean...** on Eclipse IDE

Comment: and if not solved then plz post your logcat when app is crashing

Answer (score 2):

Your Activity in not added in manifest..........

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayActivity"></activity>
```